# Data not show If multiple 3 data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i'm already create page schools and ads

This page show like this

school 1  - school 2  - school 3

**ads1**

school 4  - school 5  - school 6

**ads2**

school 7  - school  8  - school 9

**ads default** << when looping ads finished

but i have i problem when i search 1 school 
this school not show, i know this school not show because result query not multipe 3 data. if my query result 1 or 2 data. this page not show this result because this result not multiple 3 data.

This is my website : http://www.tingali.com/pencarian.html
[image]

you can search and type "**MA AL KARIMIYAH**"

This is my script :
**pagging_page3.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$limit = 24;
$adjacent = 3;

if(isset($_REQUEST['actionfunction'])  && $_REQUEST['actionfunction']!=''){
$actionfunction = $_REQUEST['actionfunction'];


   call_user_func($actionfunction,$_REQUEST,$con,$limit,$adjacent);
}
function showData($data,$con,$limit,$adjacent){
  $page  = $data['page'];
  $dt    = $_POST['dt'];

   if($page==1){
   $start = 0;  
  }
  else{
  $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
  }

      $sqlo  = "select * from schools where showschool='YES' ".$dt." and typeschool='school' order by paid,urut  asc";
      $sql   = stripslashes($sqlo);
      $rows  = $con->query($sql);
      $rows  = $rows->num_rows;

      $sqlo = "select * from schools where showschool='YES' ".$dt." and typeschool='school' order by paid,urut  asc limit $start,$limit";
      $sql   = stripslashes($sqlo);


  $data = $con->query($sql);
  $str='';
  $i=0; 
  $k=0;
  $m =1;
  $rumus = $page * ($limit / $adjacent); // bntr
  $data_web = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from web");
  $wew = ($page - 1) * 8;
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_object($data_web);

   while($row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    // This Data Ads
   if($i % 3 == 0) 
    {
        $data_ads = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from ads limit $wew,1");
        $rowads = mysqli_fetch_object($data_ads);
            $str = is_null($rowads->link) ? "<a href='#'><img src='images/ads/default/default.jpg' alt=''></a>":"<a href='".$rowads->link."'><img src='images/ads/default/".$rowads->file."' alt=''></a>";
            $wew++;
    }


        // This Data School
            $jd = $row['link'];
            $data_sl = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(kode) as counter FROM `school_counter` where kode ='".$row['kode']."' and visit between '".$row2->range_start."' AND '".$row2->range_end."' ");
            $sl = mysqli_fetch_object($data_sl);
            $str.=" <li class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4'>
            <div class='product_item'>
            <div>
            <a href='".$jd."'>
            <img height='228px' width='224px' src='images/sekolah/logo/".$row['logo']."' class='c_image_1' alt=''>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class='product_info'>
            <a href='".$jd."'><h4>".$row['name_school']."</h4></a>
            <div class='clearfix'>
            <font size='2' color='blue'>Dilihat : ".$sl->counter." </font></br>
            <i class='fa fa-home'></i> : ".$row['addres']."<br/>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </li>
            ";
    $i++;
    if ($i%3 == 0) {
        echo $str; 
        }
   }
?>
```

Help me thank's

Comment: Please at least limit the help request to a specific piece of code dont just paste the app and hope someone is willing to wade through it.

Comment: done, i update this code

Comment: That is an INCREDIBLY dangerous thing to do i.e. passing a function name in via $_POST/$_GET and then using it without ANY validation at all!?!?!?!

Comment: only searching data schools  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$adjacent = 3;
```

to

```
$adjacent = 1;
```

Comment: not fix, data not show.
you can try search 1 school.

you can type "**MA AL KARIMIYAH**"

Comment: try to change if($i % 3 == 0)  to if($i % 1 == 0)

Comment: my page utidy and show double data

i keep try 

if ($i%3 == 0) {
  echo $str; 
  }
 else if($i % 1 == 0) 
  { 
     echo $str;
  }
  
still utidy and double data

Comment: you can see this page

Comment: iam using pagging,
you want to see full coding  ?

Comment: mybe..
if i change  >>  if($i % 1 == 0) 
this result found and show my web

but i refresh my web this page utidy

Comment: if i change

if ($i%1 == 0)  {
  echo $str; 
  }

when i search 1 shools this result show on my web page.
but my collection  data show utidy and double data.
you can check this > [link](http://www.tingali.com/pencarian.html)

Comment: you can try search click to button search and type "harapan utama"
then you can see this show 1 data.

Comment: the problem fixed but my page collection data show utidy
can you have solution :(

Comment: irregular  data and double data :(

Comment: If the data is duplicated, check the sql or the bucle while, maybe you are printing twice

Comment: if i change : if($i % 3 == 0) 
data not duplicate but, i cannot find school

Comment: You could use a flag, if you have one data then do one select an exit in a while else do the code startin with if($i % 3 == 0)

Comment: can you give me example. I still confused to fix it :(